# Enable completion tracking via csv for Totara bulk course upload

Tags: moodle, totara

I need to upload a little over 2000 courses to Totara V2.6.

Doing this with a .csv file isn't normally a problem but I need to set "**Enable completion tracking**" and "**Mark as In Progress on first view**" to yes/checked for the courses.

Here is an example of what I have tried in my .csv file:

```
fullname,shortname,category,enablecompletion,completionprogressonview
COURSE NAME,COURSE NAME,1,1,1
```

The courses are created and uploaded but the two desired settings have no effect.  I have looked [here](https://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Upload_courses) for more information on uploading courses usng a .csv, but there is no mention of the **completion tracking settings**.

Is it possible to set "**Enable completion tracking**" and "**Mark as In Progress on first view**" in the .csv file, and if not is there another way I can apply these settings to all the courses without having to do it one at a time?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you can't do Enable completion tracking through a csv file for users as per the documentation: https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Upload_users

You can enable completion tracking in a separated .csv file only for courses: https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/Upload_courses#Course_information_fields

You must enable activity completion for all the activities within a course and set the course completion criteria, I don't think this can be done through a .csv, I think this must be done manually.

Once you have all users uploaded and enrolled into a course, you can change all users progress on the activities directly on the database, or create a script that does the job for you.

Comment: What  I did was change the default values in the database for "Enable completion tracking" and "Mark as In Progress on first view" to 1, and then I uploaded the .csv file and it worked. (I changed the values back to 0 after the upload seeing as I only needed them to be set to 1 for this particular instance)